# Is this unnecessary polymorphism

Tags: c#, oop

Let's say we have a base class

```
public class Equipment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

My co-worker made 4 different classes. Each of these classes introduces no new property but they all inherit directly from the base class. For example:

```
public class Tow : Equipment
public class Truck : Equipment
public class Trailer : Equipment
```

For each of these classes, there is a new file.

I personally feel this is a overkill, especially since these derived class introduces no new property. And now, you have to do boxing/unboxing.

I think a lot simpler solution would be to have the base Equipment class but have a property that says "Equipment.EquipmentType", which holds whether it's Truck, Trailer, Tow, etc. That way it's not 4 different classes.

What do you guys think is the better approach here?

Comment: "Better" entirely depends on a combination of personal opinion and the intended future growth of the system (based on business use cases).  Each approach is inherently valid and correct in and of itself.  We don't know how these objects are going to be used.

Comment: I don't see what boxing has to do with it.. they're all classes. Do you mean casting? Which was is better depends on how you're using these classes.

Comment: "And now, you have to do boxing/unboxing" - if you literally mean "boxing",  that refers to storing value types in `object` references.  You do not have that problem here.

Comment: Right now with the way it is your idea equipment type is good....but i think his/her idea is good too,their may be changes coming in the future ,where each type of equipment needs special class or they grow

Comment: If the subclasses are only ever going to be different in name, then inheritance is unnecessary. If the subclasses are going to be expanded later, then inheritance is a good design choice.

Comment: Both are valid a approaches.        
I guess your coworker's approach is a little better.        
If you add an EquipmentType property you will have to write if/else staements all the time.         
Having different classes will help you write less/simpler code.Again,both are valid though

Comment: The classes are all the same *now*, but what about *later*? Trucks and trailers have different properties - other than having wheels they have little else in common.

Comment: One important consideration is future enhancements.  Consider how to handle a situation where a new equipment type needs to be added.  Should an admin user be able to add one directly in the production system?  If so, the inheritance approach is definitely ***not*** going to make that easy.  Conversely, if equipment itself rarely changes (and can require a deployment without any fuss) but types of equipment are going to behave very differently, inheritance makes a lot of sense.